# Show $Tx=\sum^\infty _{n=1} \lambda_n \langle x , u_n \rangle v_n$ defines a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $u_n$ and $v_n$ be two orthonormal basis in a Hilbert space $H$ and let $\lambda_n$ be a bounded sequence of complex numbers.

Define  $$Tx=\sum^\infty _{n=1} \lambda_n \langle x , u_n \rangle v_n$$ $x \in H$

I am trying to prove that this defines a bounded linear operator $T: H \to H$

I am also show trying to find the norm of this operator.

> In the proof why do we first show the series is convergent?

In showing the series is convergent, we have $$\bigg| \bigg| \sum^{m+k}_{n=m} \lambda_n \langle x , u_n \rangle v_n \bigg|\bigg|^2 \leq M^2 \sum^{m+k}_{n=m} | \langle x, u_n \rangle|^2 \to 0$$

> How does this $\to 0$?
>
> why do the limits on the sum change from $\sum^\infty_{n=1}$ to
>   $\sum^{m+k}_{n=m}$
>
> Also where does $M^2$ come from?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent if $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n$ is convergent for some $m<\infty$ (i.e. you can ignore the first finitely many terms).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that, if $\{ v_n \}$ is an orthonormal subset of a Hilbert space $H$, then $\sum_{n}\alpha_n v_n$ converges in the norm of $H$ iff $\sum_{n}|\alpha_n|^2 < \infty$. And, for every $x\in H$, $\sum_{n}|(x,v_n)|^2 \le \|x\|^2 < \infty$. Therefore, $Tx=\sum_n \lambda_n (x,u_n)v_n$ converges if $|\lambda_n| \le M$ for all $n$ because
$$
         \sum_n |\lambda_n(x,u_n)|^2 \le M^2\sum_n|(x,u_n)|^2 \le M^2\|x\|^2 < \infty.
$$
Furthermore, the above gives $\|Tx\|^2 \le M^2\|x\|^2$ where $M=\sup_n|\lambda_n|$. Therefore $T$ is a bounded linear operator with $\|T\| \le M$. And, $\|T\|=M=\sup_n|\lambda_n|$ because the following holds for all $k$:
$$
            \|Te_k \|^2 = |\lambda_k|^2 \implies \|T\| \ge |\lambda_k|
     \implies \|T\|\ge \sup_{k}|\lambda_k| = M.
$$

Comment: What a fantastic answer!!